# Using some kind of pause or settimeout during while loop in node.js

Tags: node.js, while-loop

I'm using bluellinky to keep track of my car data.

I managed to fetch the data from the server and upload it to a database.
Now I need some kind of "pause" because the data is done in the wrong order. Can you please help me to add this?

This is my code:

```
// Use the MariaDB Node.js Connector and run npm install mariadb
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const { kill } = require('process');

// Create a connection pool
const pool = 
  mariadb.createPool({
    host: 'host', 
    port: port,
    user: 'user', 
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db'
});


//Bluelinky verbinden
const BlueLinky = require("bluelinky");


const client = new BlueLinky({
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  brand: 'brand', // 'hyundai', 'kia'
  region: 'country', // 'US', 'EU', 'CA'
  pin: 'pin'
});



//get yesterdays date
const repdate = new Date();
repdate.setDate(repdate.getDate()-1); // -1 => yesterday, blank => today 



// called when the client logs in successfully
client.on("ready", async () => {
  const vehicle = client.getVehicle("carnumber");
  const trpInfo = await vehicle.tripInfo({year: repdate.getFullYear(), month: repdate.getMonth()+1, day: repdate.getDate()});



if (trpInfo != '') 
    {
  
  //Erstelle Datum
  const tripdaydateraw = trpInfo[0].dayRaw.slice(4,6) + '/' + trpInfo[0].dayRaw.slice(6,8) + '/' + trpInfo[0].dayRaw.slice(0,4);
  const tripdaydate = trpInfo[0].dayRaw.slice(0,4) + '-' + trpInfo[0].dayRaw.slice(4,6) + '-' + trpInfo[0].dayRaw.slice(6,8);
  const tripdaynameraw = new Date(tripdaydateraw).toLocaleDateString('de-de', {weekday: 'long'});
  const tripdayname = tripdaynameraw;
    //Erstelle Anzahl der Fahrten
  const tripdayCnt = trpInfo[0].tripsCount;
  //Erstelle Tagesdistanz
  const tripdayDistance = trpInfo[0].distance;
  //Erstelle Tagedurchschnittsgeschwindigkeit
  const tripdayavgSpeed = trpInfo[0].speed.avg;
  //Erstelle maximale Tagesgeschwindigkeit
  const tripdaymaxSpeed = trpInfo[0].speed.max;
  
  // Errechne Anzahl der Fahrten
  let n = 0, i = tripdayCnt - 1


  while(n <= i) {
      //Restliche Werte definieren

      //Erstelle Durchschnittsgeschwindigkeit Fahrt
      const tripavgSpeed = trpInfo[0].trips[i].speed.avg;
      //Erstelle maximal Fahrgeschwindigkeit
      const tripmaxSpeed = trpInfo[0].trips[i].speed.max;
      //Startzeit
      const strttimstamp = trpInfo[0].trips[i].start;
      //Enzeit
      const endtimstamp = trpInfo[0].trips[i].end; 
      //Startdatum
      const strtdate = strttimstamp.toLocaleDateString();
      //toLocaleTimeString konvertiert GMT + 1, Startzeit
      const strtime = strttimstamp.toLocaleTimeString() ;
      //Enddatum
      const enddate = endtimstamp.toLocaleDateString();
      //toLocaleTimeString konvertiert GMT + 1, Endzeit
      const endtime = endtimstamp.toLocaleTimeString();

      //Fahrzeit in Minuten
      const drvtime_minutes = trpInfo[0].trips[i].durations.drive;

      //Stehzeit in Minuten
      const idletime_minutes = trpInfo[0].trips[i].durations.idle;

      //Distanz
      const drvdistance = trpInfo[0].trips[i].distance;

      //Tankrechnung
      const refuel_amt = '0.00'

      //Werte Ausgeben
      const tripinfodata = tripdaydate + ', ' + tripdayCnt + ', ' + tripdayDistance + ', ' + tripdayavgSpeed + ', ' + tripdaymaxSpeed + ', ' + tripavgSpeed + ', ' + tripmaxSpeed + ', ' + strtime + ', ' + endtime + ', ' + drvtime_minutes + ', ' + drvdistance + ', ' + tripdayname;
      
      //SQL Statement bauen
      let connection

      try {
      connection = await pool.getConnection()
      } catch(error) {
        //not connected
        pool.end()
        return // or: log and/or throw error again
      }

      // run insert query
      const queryString = "INSERT INTO nightfury_trips (tripdaydate, tripdayCnt, tripdayDistance, tripdayavgSpeed, tripdaymaxSpeed, tripavgSpeed, tripmaxSpeed, strtime, endtime, drvtime_minutes, idletime_minutes, drvdistance, tripdayname, refuel_amt) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
      const queryData = [tripdaydate, tripdayCnt, tripdayDistance, tripdayavgSpeed, tripdaymaxSpeed, tripavgSpeed, tripmaxSpeed, strtime, endtime, drvtime_minutes, idletime_minutes, drvdistance, tripdayname, refuel_amt]

      let rowsInserted
      try {
        rowsInserted = connection.query(queryString, queryData)
      } catch (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
        connection.end();
        
        // continue on the next loop
        n -= 1;
        continue;
      }
  
      // rows inserted successfully, log them
      console.log(rowsInserted)
      
      n -= 1
    }
  
    pool.end()
    console.log('finished!')
  }
  
  // call myLoop.
  // this is an async function
  myLoop()
    .then(() => console.log('myLoop finished!'))
    .catch((error) => console.error('unexpected error:', error))
});
```

**UPDATE 04.05.2023 22:14**

thanks @dave newton for your fast response. The result looks like this:

```
2023-05-04, 2, 3, 41, 89, 35, 60, 20:37:02, 20:42:02, 5, 2, Donnerstag
2023-05-04, 2, 3, 41, 89, 47, 89, 07:49:48, 07:52:48, 3, 1, Donnerstag
```

But I want to have the other way around, sorted by the timestamp ascending; thats why I use "i -= 1", but it does not always work, I think it's because for the lag between hyundai server and my machine.

**UPDATE 06.05.2023 08:06**

@tmilar: It works thanks to you, but I have now the problem with multiple returns, example, yesterday I was driving four times, but the log gave me 10 times

```
PS C:\Users\Josi\Downloads\bluelinky> node nightfury_trip_DBupload_sorted.js
Register request has failed with Error=PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR
Retry... 1
Register request has failed with Error=PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR
Retry... 2
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the exact problem is, or if the issue is actually in this code. It **sounds** like it's an issue happening before the code shown, e.g., dealing with the results of async operations.

Comment: Your question and the provided code (in their current state) are hard to understand. What is happening, what's the issue, what is the code doing, what is the input, what is the desired output? You cannot just throw code at us without providing more context and clarification. Please [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are running your call to store the data in your DB, which is a Promise / async operation, inside a `while` loop without using any mechanism to wait for the operations to be completed before each next loop iteration.

A way to solve this would be using async/await operator.

Here is a basic example:

```js
async function myLoop() {

  // ... some initial logic
  
  while (n <= i) {

    // ... logic to read your data for this loop iteration goes here

    // retrieve connection
    let connection 
  
    try {
      connection = await pool.getConnection()
    } catch(error) {
      // not connected
      pool.end()
      return // or: log and/or throw error again
    }
    
    // run insert query
    const queryString = "INSERT INTO nightfury_trips (tripdaydate, tripdayCnt, tripdayDistance, tripdayavgSpeed, tripdaymaxSpeed, tripavgSpeed, tripmaxSpeed, strtime, endtime, drvtime_minutes, idletime_minutes, drvdistance, tripdayname, refuel_amt) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
    const queryData = [tripdaydate, tripdayCnt, tripdayDistance, tripdayavgSpeed, tripdaymaxSpeed, tripavgSpeed, tripmaxSpeed, strtime, endtime, drvtime_minutes, idletime_minutes, drvdistance, tripdayname, refuel_amt]

    let rowsInserted
    try {
      rowsInserted = connection.query(queryString, queryData)
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
      connection.end();
      
      // continue on the next loop
      n -= 1;
      continue;
    }

    // rows inserted successfully, log them
    console.log(rowInserted)
    
    n -= 1
  }

  pool.end()
  console.log('finished!')
}

// call myLoop.
// this is an async function
myLoop()
  .then(() => console.log('myLoop finished!'))
  .catch((error) => console.error('unexpected error:', error))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm too stupid to get it running, I read a lot of web pages, but it seems that my english is not good enough to understand the logic from await sync.
In my original post I add the full code with your enhancements, can you please tell the initial logic? THANKS